# Row height proportion according to window size changes

Tags: css

Hi I'm new to web development and learn CSS with Bootstrap in Codecademy.

I have 3 components in the `body`, and I would like to set there `height` according to the windows size.

```
header {height:15%;}
main   {height:75%;}
footer {height:10%;}
```

I know how to do with column but not row. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parent element has – and the `<html>` and `<body>` elements have – a defined height of `100%` then you can use the same percentages in the CSS for the elements:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 15%;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 75%;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Of course, this will result in a vertical scroll if there's any padding or margins set (even by default) on any of these elements; so they should be set to `0`:

```css
html, body, div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 15%;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 75%;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Or, instead of using percentage units, you could instead use `vh`; `1vh` is equal to `1%` of the viewport-height; this avoids having to set `height: 100%` on the `<html>` and `<body>` elements:

```css
.header {
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

But, of course, because of `padding` and `margin` this still results in a scroll-bar, so setting those to `0` &ndash again – is still required:

```css
html, body, div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Or, although `margin` will still need to be explicitly set to `0`, you could force the browser to include any `padding` within the height/width calculations of the elements by setting `box-sizing` to `border-box`.

This addresses the problem that the height/width of an element is usually calculated and is then increased by any padding and any borders. `border-box` forces the browser to set an element's height, or width, *including* the size of the border and padding:

```css
html, body, div {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)<sup>[compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing), [specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui-3/#box-sizing)</sup>.
- [CSS Values and Units Module, Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just missing the `height` on the parents, which are `body` and `html` tags.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  height: 15%;
}
main {
  height: 75%;
}
footer {
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Or, you could use viewport units.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  height: 15vh;
}
main {
  height: 75vh;
}
footer {
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```css
body {
 width: 36%;
 margin: 8px auto;
}

div.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 position: relative;

 background: red;
}

div.wrapper > div {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;

 color: white;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div>See in fullscreen mode</div></div>
```